# Python Object Element Extraction and Addition

Tags: python

I’m sure all experienced Python programmers know a simple, elegant way to do this. Unfortunately, at my beginner’s level, I do not.

Anyway, I’m currently attempting to modify some AI scripts for a game program written by others. I’m looking for a way to extract the numeric elements from an existing object and then add all of those elements together.

The number of elements in the object will vary, but will usually be no more then ten (10).

The elements in the object will always be ‘floats’.

So, for i in obj:

How should I proceed to extract all of the elements from the existing object and then add them together to return a new ‘float’ number?

Comment: Many thanks to everyone that responded to my question. The answers are all there!

Comment: Remember to select the answer you think is best/most helpful (click on the green checkmark by it).

Comment: Your question is a little unclear -- can you edit it and post an example of an object you want summed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sum(iterable)` to add up all the items in a tuple or list.

`sum([1,2,3])` returns `6`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you want:

```
total=0
for i in obj:
    total+=i
```

Comment: Works, but not as pythonic as `total = sum(obj)`

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
for attr, val in vars(obj).iteritems():
    sum += val
```

That should iterate though all of the objects attributes and add them all to a `sum` variable.

Comment: My bad, simple typo, changed the variable name now.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `sum(iterable)` is the immediate answer- if you need a generalization, try `reduce(func, iterable)` (Python 2.x) or `functools.reduce(func, iterable)` (Python 3). Eg, to get the product of a list of numbers, `reduce(operator.mul, [1,2,3,4])` which returns 24.